# How do I integrate device driver to ros

Tags: linux-device-driver, ros

so I know a little bit about writing Linux kernel device drivers. And I wrote a device driver for my game controller. The problem is, I want to integrate my device driver to ROS. How should I do that? I don't want to use the pre-existing packages for ROS. And I tried to look for the documentation but to no avail. So, Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: This is side about code. Where is your code? What is the problem precisely you are trying to solve?

Comment: I feel like this is a solved problem already, for most game controllers. The ros-joy package/node should be sufficient.

Comment: @JWCS yes, I am aware of ros-joy package/node, but I am trying to understand the workings of writing a Linux device driver and integrating it into ROS. Purely for self-learning. I am not only interested in publishing and subscribing to the topics and writing a node but the entire chain. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ROS is a strongly-typed messaging system, that wraps the real math/code up, to provide a generic interface via topics and messages. Write your code, write a ROS node, call your code from the ROS node, and define the publishers/subscribers/interface you want other nodes to talk to you by.

Comment: https://roboticsbackend.com/create-a-ros-driver-package-introduction-what-is-a-ros-wrapper-1-4/ I am using ros wrappers concept similar to the above link

Comment: Good link there 